# When I try to open an image using cv2.imshow(), a blank image window pops up

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

When I try to open an image using `cv2.imshow()`, a blank image window pops up. I've tried using `cv2.waitKey()` and `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`, but doesn't work.

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img1=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

cv2.imshow('original image',img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

[Blank image  window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfNcO.jpg)

Comment: `img=cv2.imread('image path')` you sure that `image path` is a valid image name? Also, you might want to modify the argument to the `waitKey` function, maybe pass `0` to it, to keep the window open until you manually close it. And last, but not least, if the image is too big, you might be seeing just a portion of it, as the image is not automatically scaled.

Comment: Does the same happen if you display `img` instead of `img1`?

Comment: Yes @kindustrii for all images, result is same

Comment: @eldesgraciado 'image path' was just a temporary name I used in the above code. Consider 'img.jpg' then. Also I tried rescaling image, but didn't work at all

Comment: Try printing `img.shape` and `img.dtype` immediately after loading it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Image didn't show up but img shape is (3456, 5184 , 3) and img dtype is uint8

Comment: @MarkSetchell I rescaled that image to scale 1/4 and it worked! Thanks a lot!